# Threading udp datas with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

I'm trying to implement UDP socket's threading.

I want to be able to wait for clients to send me some data in a thread and wait for first datas in an other.

```
import threading
import socket

class Broker():

    def __init__(self):
          self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
          self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4242))
          self.clients_list = []

    def talkToClient(self, ip):
            self.sock.sendto("ok", ip)

    def listen_clients(self):
            while True:
                msg, client = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
                t = threading.Thread(None, self.talkToClient, None, (client,), None)

b = Broker()
b.listen_clients()
```

and my client

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

sock.sendto("connection", ('127.0.0.1', 4242))

while True:
    msg, b = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print msg
```

Problem is that my client is never receiving "ok"

Comment: Hi Zeena, how is your UDP server coming along? Anything unclear about my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are not starting the thread that you have created.

```
t.start()
```

Should do it. Please make sure you are using four spaces for indentation as well.

I didn't see the error first myself, but once I added some logging statements it was pretty obvious. The code ended up looking like this:

```
import threading
import socket
import logging

class Broker():

    def __init__(self):
        logging.info('Initializing Broker')
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4242))
        self.clients_list = []

    def talkToClient(self, ip):
        logging.info("Sending 'ok' to %s", ip)
        self.sock.sendto("ok", ip)

    def listen_clients(self):
        while True:
            msg, client = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
            logging.info('Received data from client %s: %s', client, msg)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.talkToClient, args=(client,))
            t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make sure all log messages show up
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    b = Broker()
    b.listen_clients()
```

I'm afraid you will run into other problems however, because of your threaded solution. Most python modules are not thread-safe by default, unfortunately this is [true for the socket module as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177018/python-socket-and-threads). I'm pretty sure that eventually your socket's internal state will be corrupted since you are reading in one thread and writing in another, or potentially in many others since you spawn a new process for each client.

If you look at [multi-threaded socket code examples](https://gist.github.com/micktwomey/606178) in Python, a socket is usually  owned and used by only one thread. The key is to not reuse the listening socket for clients, but to use [`socket.accept`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) to create a new socket for each client once it has connected.

Comment: Is the clients-list usefull for this example ?

Comment: No it's not used. I must have copied it from the question. 