# Python console chat with socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm writing a simple console chat with server and client. When receiving a message from the first client server should send it to the second client and vice versa. But when first client sends a message to the server it returns back and doesn't reach the second client. Maybe there is a problem in `receiving()` function.

Here is my `client.py`:

```
import socket
from _thread import *


def recieving(clientSocket):
    while True:
        encodedMsg = clientSocket.recv(1024)
        decodedMsg = encodedMsg.decode('utf-8')

        print(decodedMsg)


def chat(clientSocket, name):
    msg = input()
    encoded_msg = f'[{name}] {msg}'.encode('utf-8')

    clientSocket.send(encoded_msg)


def main():
    serverAddress = (socket.gethostname(), 4444)

    clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientSocket.connect(serverAddress)

    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    start_new_thread(recieving, (clientSocket,))
    while True:
        chat(clientSocket, name)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And `server.py`:

```
import time
import socket
from _thread import *


def listen(clientSocket, addr):
    while True:
        encodedMsg = clientSocket.recv(1024)
        decodedMsg = encodedMsg.decode('utf-8')
        currTime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S", time.localtime())
    
        for client in clients:
            if addr != client:
                clientSocket.sendto(encodedMsg, client)

    print(f'[{currTime}] {decodedMsg}')


def main():
    serverAddress = (socket.gethostname(), 4444)
    global clients
    clients = []

    serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.bind(serverAddress)
    serverSocket.listen(2)

    while True:
        clientSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)
            print(f'{addr} joined chat')

        start_new_thread(listen, (clientSocket, addr))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `socket.gethostname()` didn't work on my mac, probably because the hostname isn't in /etc/hosts.  This implementation would be equivalent if you used localhost `127.0.0.1` address and would remove the dependency on name resolution

Comment: `socket.gethostname()` works fine on my Mac

Comment: because you can resolve your hostname to an address.  Check your `/etc/hosts`.  There's nothing wrong with using hostname to resolve, it just adds a pointless dns lookup when you know the address you wactually want is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I think this is your bug:  `                clientSocket.sendto(encodedMsg, client)` you actually want to send to `client`, but `clientSocket` is already connected to the client it's listening from, so you end up sending messages only to that client.  If you try with 3 clients, you'll see the sending client gets the message once for each `sendto` on the sending client's socket.  [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto) says "The socket should not be connected to a remote socket, since the destination socket is specified by address."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendto` doesn't work as expected if its socket is connected.  It just sends to the connected socket, not the specified address.

Therefore, `listen` needs to be able to access the open socket of each client in order to write to it.

Currently `clients` is a list of addresses, but you could change it to a dict of address to socket mappings:

```
def main():
    global clients
    clients = {}
```

Then when you get a new client connection, save address and socket:

```
        clientSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

        if addr not in clients:
            clients[addr] = clientSocket
            print(f'{addr} joined chat')

        start_new_thread(listen, (clientSocket, addr))
```

Finally, in listen, write to each other client's socket, not the connected `clientSocket` for that `listen` thread:

```
        for client in clients:
            if addr != client:
                print(f"sending message from {addr} to {client}")
                clients[client].send(encodedMsg)
```

There's a number of other problems with your code.

Sockets are [not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177018/python-socket-and-threads#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%2CThe%20socket%20shared%20by,thread%20is%20not%20thread%20safe.).  So there is a race condition if 2 clients happen to write the same thing at the same time; the writes could be interpolated and the messages munged up.

If a client disconnects, the server doesn't handle the disconnection well.  If the server disconnects, the clients go into an infinite loop as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for noticing some other problems